# Writing a custom program for MS Excel

Tags: xml, excel

I have never programmed anything for MS excel, and not much for MS OS in general,  and now must do so.

Context: Create an excel template that loads an xml file, and acts as a gui editor for editing said xml file.  Rows, Columns, select fields with multiple options.

Export the edited file back out.

I am having a hell of a time figuring out where to start.  Does excel have these capabilities native to it? Must I use VB, VBA, or C#?  Any recommendations from an experienced excel developer on the appropriate language to use will be much appreciated.

I have already created the web editor for this and must admit, it is freakin' fantastic.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/305795#bookmark-5

Comment: Thank you for the link.  I will go with VBA for this project.